# Removing a node from xml file

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<category>
  <name>SWEATERS</name>
  <name>WATCHES</name>
  <name>PANTS</name>
  <name>test</name>
  <name>1</name>
</category>
```

How i can remove the node `<name>test</name>` using xpath ,xquery and php. I used this code

```
 $name='test;
    $xmlfile="config/shop_categories.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
    $target = $xml->xpath('/category[name="'.trim($name).'"]');
    print_r($target[0]);
    if($target == false)
    return; 
    $domRef = dom_import_simplexml($target[0]); //Select position 0 in XPath array
    $domRef->parentNode->removeChild($domRef);
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
    $dom->save($xmlfile);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: The main problem is that your XPath query returns the `category` node, rather than the `name` as you intended. Gordon's answer doesn't mention that (at the time of writing) but fixes the issue.

Comment: @salathe right, actually i didnt pay attention to that detail because that simplexml to dom mishmash made no sense to me anyway.

Comment: @Gordon, no worries. Now the OP has an answer *and* a fix. :)

Comment: @THOmas: Your question is about DOM method. XPath is for querying an XML document, not transforming.

Comment: @Alejandro it's certainly not about xquery but it surely is about xpath, because that's what you pass to the DOM method and that's also where the issue lay in this case.

Comment: @Gordon: No. The answer is about `removeChild()` method. You pass a node reference to that method, not an XPath expression. How you get that node reference is pointless: it could be XPath, it could be other DOM method. Also, for other people searching, this could be confuse because XPath doesn't change the document.

Comment: @Alejandro You pass an XPath expression to the `query()` method (or `xpath` method in the OP's code). This is where the code was wrong. The actual removal is done with `removeChild` which you pass a node. But to get that node, the OP explicitly wants to use XPath (or XQuery, which is non-applicable). XPath is one piece of the puzzle here, because like @salathe already pointed out, the used XPath will not return the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but am too lazy to find it. Here you go:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<category>
  <name>SWEATERS</name>
  <name>WATCHES</name>
  <name>PANTS</name>
  <name>test</name>
  <name>1</name>
</category>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xPath->query('//name[text() = "test"]') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<category>
  <name>SWEATERS</name>
  <name>WATCHES</name>
  <name>PANTS</name>

  <name>1</name>
</category>
```